# Missing formatting after adding childnode?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to add a childnode in an XML document with PHP and got it OK so far except one thing. Can't get it formatted correct?

Here is the script:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xmldoc->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <udate>1347730639</udate>
  <userid>3</userid>
</data>');

echo "<xmp>OLD:\n". $xmldoc->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

$root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

$newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('popup');
$root->appendChild($newElement);
$newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode("0");
$newElement->appendChild($newText);

echo "<xmp>NEW:\n". $xmldoc->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
```

After adding the node I get this:

```
<data>
  <udate>1347730639</udate>
  <userid>3</userid>
<popup>0</popup></data>
```

I want it to be like this:

```
<data>
  <udate>1347730639</udate>
  <userid>3</userid>
  <popup>0</popup>
</data>
```

Where do I go wrong?

Please help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createElement` will break `formatOutput` this is a general issue

See PHP BUG Report

- [formatOutput does not work with saveHTML](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48509)
- [DOMDocument->formatOutput = true does not work](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54972)

But you can have a work around  by reloading and formatting it.

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <udate>1347730639</udate>
  <userid>3</userid>
</data>');

echo "<xmp>OLD:\n". $xmldoc->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

$root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

$newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('popup');
$root->appendChild($newElement);
$newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode("0");
$newElement->appendChild($newText);



$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->loadXML( $xmldoc->saveXML());
echo "<xmp>NEW:\n". $xml->saveXML()."</xmp>";
```

Output

```
OLD:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <udate>1347730639</udate>
  <userid>3</userid>
</data>
NEW:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <udate>1347730639</udate>
  <userid>3</userid>
  <popup>0</popup>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try removing all whitespace before and then formatting.

force it to remake the xml from scratch.

```
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$xml->formatOutput = true;
```

Comment: I think you should always test your code before posting it  .. you might attract downvote if you don't do so